# "An object reference is required to access non-static member unityengine.transform.localrotation"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static-members

Running into this error a lot recently.

> An object reference is required to access non-static member unityengine.transform.localrotation

```
    if(RotXY == RotationAxis.MouseX) {
        RotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse.X") * SensitivityX * Time.deltaTime;
        Quaternion XQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(RotationX, Vector3.up);
        Transform.localRotation = OriginalRotation * XQuaternion;
    }
```

What exactly do I need to do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a typo mistake. You have to use transform not Transform. Transform is a class and you can not access its member directly. it should be like this.

```
transform.localRotation = OriginalRotation * XQuaternion;
```

Comment: Wow... well that's that then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that `unityengine.transform.localrotation` is not static. That means it cannot be accessed using the `ClassName.memberName` syntax. You have to create am *instance* of the `Transform` class. I don't really know what `Transform` is but you either need to call its constructer or a method that returns a `Transform` object.